# Data binding Wpf with textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **screen** like this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZhbm.png)

The Input condition is :

- 0  - 4  : Baby (red)
- 5  - 10 : Kid (green)
- 11 - 14 : Children (blue)
- 15 - 18 : Teens (yellow)
- 18 - 23 : Adults (organe)

So When I import "23" it will show "Adults" and "Orange" color!

Could anyone help me,please ?

Comment: You Forgot to post your code :)

Comment: You could put a trigger on your `setter` of the input property, and that trigger then changes the text and color

Comment: @user2657943: Trigger does not check for range.

Comment: Depends on how you make one...

Comment: If any of the below answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

So, there will be 2 converters used in this

1. For Showing Name like Baby, Adult
2. For Showing Colour.

Trigger won't help here because trigger check only Equals and not for other operators like `!=` or `<` or `>`. For that you have to use converters.

Both converters will take your Age property and will return value and colour based on conditions like this.

Comment: How about setting Baby or Kid etc. in the setter of Age?

Comment: I guess you are talking of Triggers. Trigger does not check for range.

Comment: No, not triggers. I am talking about setting words in CLR property setter on lost focus.

Comment: You could. But then that code will be a ViewModel Function. Putting in converter, we can use it in xaml and in ViewModel also.

Comment: Converters are just more flexible and clean. When you would want to change the functionality of a certain element, you can just swap a converter that is bound, instead of rewriting everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of two converters, that would read the value from textbox and return appropriate data (Text & Color).

**Age Range to Text Converter:**

```
class RangeToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int age = (int)value;
        string output = "";

        if (age >= 0 && age <= 4)
        {
            output = "Baby";
        }
        else if (age >= 5 && age <= 10)
        {
            output = "Kid";
        }
        else if (age >= 11 && age <= 14)
        {
            output = "Children";
        }
        else if (age >= 15 && age <= 18)
        {
            output = "Teens";
        }
        else if (age >= 18 && age <= 23)
        {
            output = "Adult";
        }

        return output;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**Age Range to Color Converter:**

```
class RangeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int age = (int)value;
        Brush output = Brushes.Transparent;

        if (age >= 0 && age <= 4)
        {
            output = Brushes.Red;
        }
        else if (age >= 5 && age <= 10)
        {
            output = Brushes.Green;
        }
        else if (age >= 11 && age <= 14)
        {
            output = Brushes.Blue;
        }
        else if (age >= 15 && age <= 18)
        {
            output = Brushes.Yellow;
        }
        else if (age >= 18 && age <= 23)
        {
            output = Brushes.Orange;
        }

        return output;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This is how you can use the converters:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.YourClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceWhereYourConvertersAre"
        Title="ConverterSample" Height="140" Width="250">
        <Window.Resources>
                <local:RangeToTextConverter x:Key="RangeToTextConverter " />
                <local:ColorToTextConverter x:Key="ColorToTextConverter " />
        </Window.Resources>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBox Name="txtValue" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=txtValue, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource RangeToTextConverter}}" />
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ElementName=txtValue, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ColorToTextConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I would create properties for the brushes, so the actual brushes can still be defined in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution without converters because I find them to be a bit overkill sometimes

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private int _num;

    public int Num
    {
        get => _num;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _num)) return;
            _num = value;


            if (value >= 0 && value <= 4)
            {
                Col = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else if (value >= 5 && value <= 10)
            {
                Col = Brushes.Green;
            }
            else if (value >= 11 && value <= 14)
            {
                Col = Brushes.Blue;
            }
            else if (value >= 15 && value <= 18)
            {
                Col = Brushes.Yellow;
            }
            else if (value >= 18 && value <= 23)
            {
                Col = Brushes.Orange;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Brush _col;
    public Brush Col
    { 
        get => _col;
        set {
            _col = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main reason for using converters instead of properties in Code-Behind of a ViewModel, is that it's easy to just swap it for a different one, without the need to modify your ViewModel. Following SOLID principles and multiple guidelines of "good" coding, it is implied to create solutions that are extensible, and do not require modification of your code-behind (or as few modification as needed). Also, this doesn't seem problematic in such a trivial example, but the bigger the project gets - the more clustered the ViewModel will be.

Nevertheless, it IS a valid solution.

Comment: How valid it is to include Brushes in ViewModel ??

Comment: @NareshRavlani Including Brushes in ViewModel could be valid in very many cases, and invalid in many others. You would need a specific context to decide. In this context, however, I would go with value converters. As to why, please refer to my comment above.